# Is there any way of sending on POST data with a Redirect in an MVC3 controller?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form which is posted to an MVC3 controller that then has to be POSTED to an external URL. The browser need to go to the URL permanently so I thought a permanent redirect would be perfect.
However, how do I send the form POST data with the redirect?

I don't really want to send another page down to the browser to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A redirect will always to be a GET, not a POST.

If the 2nd POST doesn't need to come from the client, you can make the POST using HttpWebRequest from the server.  Beware the secondary POST may hold up the return of the client request if the external server is down or running slowly.

Comment: Will a WebRequest redirect the actual browser, wouldn't I have to send the response down to the browser and it will stay on my server?

Comment: No it won't redirect the browser - the bottom line is you can't redirect a post.  You could do something fancy with some JavaScript if you need the browser to automatically make the post (e.g. return the form that needs posting and a script to submit that form).

Comment: Aye cheers. I've sent another page and submitted the form in the body onload. Thanks to you both. Sorry site won't let me vote you both up :(

Comment: I think anyone can upvote anything - you can only accept one answer though.

Answer (score 0):

A permanent redirect is wholly inappropriate here. First, it will not cause form values to be resubmitted. Second, the semantics are all wrong - you would be telling the browser "do not request this url again. instead, go here". However, you *do* want future submissions to go to your same url.

Gaz's idea could work. It involves your server, only.

Alternatively, send a form with the same submitted values and the external URL, and use client-side code to automatically submit it.

Comment: Yeah, I said I didn't really want to send a page down to the browser but I think it's the only way to get that browser to the external domain, which is where it must end up. Thanks